# MailChimp API 2.0 Batch Subscription PHP

Tags: php, mailchimp

I am not able to subscribe multiple emails in MailChimp. Using API https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mailchimp-api-php/downloads

```
$api_key = "***";
$list_id = "***";

require ('api/Mailchimp.php');
$Mailchimp = new Mailchimp($api_key);
$Mailchimp_Lists = new Mailchimp_Lists($Mailchimp);


$batch[] = array('email' => 'user1@mail.com');
$batch[] = array('email' => 'user2@mail.com');

$subscriber = $Mailchimp_Lists -> batchSubscribe($list_id, $batch, false, false, true);
```

I am getting following Error:

```
[errors] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [code] => -99
                [error] => An email address must contain a single @
                [email] => user1@mail.com
            )
        [0] => Array
            (
                [code] => -99
                [error] => An email address must contain a single @
                [email] => user2@mail.com
            )

    )
```

Comment: Its better you ask to MailChimp support and you must validate email id before adding it to batch array

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Email should be a struct, not a string.

```
$batch[] = array('email' => 'user1@mail.com');
$batch[] = array('email' => 'user2@mail.com');
```

Should be

```
$batch[] = array('email' => array('email' => 'user1@mail.com'));
$batch[] = array('email' => array('email' => 'user2@mail.com'));
```

Comment: Not working for me...it throws the error ( [0] => Array ( [code] => -99 [error] => This email address looks fake or invalid. Please enter a real email address [email] => Array ( [email] => 3005sathish@example.com ) )

Comment: @Digant Probably because that's not a real email. `@example.com` is a reserved domain by [IANA](http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved). Mailchimp most likely do checks against the list.