# Hugofirth Mailchimp Wrapper Error

Tags: php, laravel, mailchimp

Whenever i try to get member info like so.
`MailchimpWrapper::list()->memberInfo($list_id, ["example@email.com"]);`

I get the following response

```
array(4) {
  ["success_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(19) "example@email.com"
      ["error"]=>
      string(26) ""email" should be a struct"
      ["code"]=>
      int(-100)
    }
  }
  ["data"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23827736/804741

Comment: @Ravan thanks, but there seems to be another problem, i now get an error that say. `The id passed does not exist on this list` while the email actually does exist.

Comment: @mariotanenbaum Yup, just posted the answer!

Answer (score 0):

After asking a question [here](https://github.com/hugofirth/laravel-mailchimp/issues/34), this was the answer i got.

You need to pass a multidimensional array (which is what is meant by a struct in this case) as the second argument since a user can have multiple email addresses:

Change:

`MailchimpWrapper::list()->memberInfo($list_id, 
 ["example@email.com"]);`

to:

```
MailchimpWrapper::list()->memberInfo($list_id, 
['emails' => 
    ['email' => 'example@email.com']
]);
```